# gwt> importing a sample project

Tags: eclipse, gwt, import, sample

I'm just barely after 2 hours of trying to force it to work and looking for answers online.

How in the world do you import a sample gwt application into your eclipse and make it run?

by the way, I cannot find "projectCreator.cmd" anywhere in my files, where is it suppose to be assumming i've used eclipse plugin updater to d/l gwt 1.7.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is what I ended up doing though it ugly and probably not how it was meant to be:

I create a new application called it "bla" or whatever
then right on  project > import... > general\file system... (as in import files into projects)

then I selected the top folder of one of the sample applications, for example ..gwt..samples/Mail

selected all folders and files.
selected option "override without warning\asking"
de-selected option "copy entire folder structure"

that's about it. I went to build.XML to rename the project name to "bla" and then I clicked run as a web application.

good luck.

Comment: Tanx big. was all over the web before i found your working solution. what other hacks do i need to do to make all the projects work perfectly. do i need to add any apis?

Answer (score 0):

For GWT 2.4: In every project's root you will find a `README.txt`. If you follow its directions (involving creation of Eclipse project configuration via Ant) you can import the project easily. To run it I additionally had to configure the project's GWT settings (project's context menu -> Google -> WebToolkit settings).

Comment: Unfortunately the README.txt says the first step is to run "ant eclipse.generate" to generate .project and .classpath files. This is difficult for people like me who only use Eclipse and don't have the ant environment setup.

Comment: You probably have `ant` on your computer. Just have a look into `your Eclipse installation directory > plugins > org.apache.ant__1.8.3.v20120321-1730` (maybe a different version). This is the complete runtime that Eclipse uses for ant projects if no other is specified. Just put `bin` into the path and run the command you mentioned to create the Eclipse project setup.

Answer (score 0):

First, Create an Eclipse project for your source, if you haven't already done so, by selecting File > New > Java Project. Then choose Create project from existing source and set up your project. At this point, your source will be loaded in Eclipse, but the project's build path may not be set up properly, and you may see build errors.

**Alternatively**, if your application's source tree already contains a .project file, either because you had previously worked on it in Eclipse or because it was generated by a tool like GWT's webAppCreator, you can import the project by going to File > Import > General and selecting Existing Projects into Workspace

To enable Google Web Toolkit, right-click your project and select Google > Web Toolkit Settings. Check the Use Google Web Toolkit box and click OK to apply the change.

Enabling App Engine for your project is similar: right-click your project and select Google > App Engine Settings. Check the Use Google App Engine box and click OK.

**Source** : https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/existingprojects

Answer (score 0):

What I did to start it:

My workspace is at: /Users/ievgennaloiko/Documents/helpdesk/
I have downloaded the gwt to Downloads folder. Extracted it. Navigated from terminal to samples and run

```
ant eclipse.generate
```

for each sample project I need to import to Eclipse. Even you can run this command on whole sample project.

Next I've copied the samples folder to /Users/ievgennaloiko/Documents/helpdesk
Started Eclipse.
File import -> Existing proj into ws -> /Users/ievgennaloiko/Documents/helpdesk/samples/DynaTable

Copy project into ws - Unchecked.

Next I had to go to properties of the project Google-WebToolkit->Use web toolkit.

Here are the arguments I run with, check for correspondence:

```
-remoteUI "${gwt_remote_ui_server_port}:${unique_id}" -logLevel INFO -port 
auto - codeServerPort 9997 -war 
/Users/ievgennaloiko/Documents/helpdesk/samples/DynaTable/war
     com.google.gwt.sample.dynatable.DynaTable
```