# GWT Import into Eclipse Kepler

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, gwt2

I am trying to import a GWT into Eclipse Kepler. I deleted the old version of AwardTracker_N from the work space and am trying to import a copy I made in another directory. I am using File/Import/Existing projects into workspace. I then select Select root directory and browse to the copy. I then get a message "Some projects can not be imported because they already exist in the workspace", and I can not continue.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Glyn

Comment: Have you look at the folder still exists in Disk ? You might deleted from eclipse. Check in disk as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777183/gwt-importing-a-sample-project

Comment: Hi Suresh, yes I deleted the old project form the workspace. Regards, Glyn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating the project and importing the old project as a file.